# Jenkins Plugin installation issue

Tags: java, jenkins

I am not able to install any plugins after I upgraded my jenkins version.
I can understand it is a certificate error. Could you please let me know the resolution?

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Not sure about the java version that you're using to run jenkins but this exception usually means  Certificate Authority is not known to Java. This happens when companies use their own CAs for URLs. How are you installing plugin ? There's an offline plugin install option if you have access to .hpi/.jpi files

Comment: I install though manage plugins..what is the other option? Off-line plugins ? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkin, jdk version  8/11 is required. If you are using JDK version 8 then upgrade it to version 11. This is one of the possible solution as you didn't mention the Jenkin version or the java version. There is other ways to solve certificate issue, like you can install the certificate, but the easiest way is to upgrade jdk version.